# Layout designing on Android Board

Tags: android

I'm designing a game board in Android. I need to put a button and an image view in between Admob and the board. I am able to do so, but it is having compatibility problem because I have hard coded the values like height and width. I want to know how I can do it without hard coded values. Please help me.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverlow. Please read the FAQ. There are tips that you should follow to improve your question. The current one is missing a real question and your xml layout...

Answer (score 0):

Dont use hard code height and width. 
1. You must use dip unit instead of pixels.
2. set layout_width and layout_height as either WRAP_CONTENT or FILL_PARENT
3. Dont use AbsoluteLayout
4. Use layout_weight,layout_marginleft,layout_marginright....etc properties.